# When building in Unity, I get an error and I can't figure out how to solve it

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

I've been looking for some solutions, but none of them helped me. It is not likely to matter, but if I make a build for Windows, everything works fine. I'm new to C# and Unity, so I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do. My Unity version is 2022.3.9f1.
Error:

````
D:\Programs\Unity\2022.3.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Gradle\gradle-8.3\lib\gradle-launcher-8.3.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"



stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type BuildTreeActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildTreeScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<BuildActionRunner>.
   > Could not create service of type FileHasher using GradleUserHomeServices.createCachingFileHasher().
      > Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (C:\Users\Максим\.gradle\caches\8.3\fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
        Owner PID: 5464
        Our PID: 13892
        Owner Operation: 
        Our operation: 
        Lock file: C:\Users\Максим\.gradle\caches\8.3\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)```

I tried stopping all Gradle processes through the terminal, restarting the computer, and trying to install Gradle separately, but none of these things solved the problem. I also tried to build a different version of Unity (2023.1.0b20), but it again did not give any result.
````

Comment: First make sure you have JDK installed in your system, then go to `Edit > Preferences > External Tools`, Uncheck the option to use JDK that came with unity, and navigate to your system JDK instead. Every Unity version has a specific JDK that it uses. For your version it's `JDK11` so make sure you install that JDK version.

Comment: I tried doing as you said, but the error still appears

Comment: You can try to remove `Library` folder in your project directory to clean build cache.